# Help me make this noob code more idiomatic

Tags: clojure

So I am using congomongo (the fetch function near the end) to pull some documents from a mongodb collection. I want to pass options through to the fetch call, so i can do something like `(posts :limit 1)` and have `{:limit 1}` get passed through to fetch. I am doing hand rolled "memoization" with `@posts`, because i want to be able to reset the cache, which to my understanding cant be done with `clojure.core/memoize`.

Now, the problem I see here is that `(fetch :posts options)` call is non trivial, and I would really rather not hammer my datastore if dosync has to retry the transaction. I am a total clojure/fp noob though, and I am not sure how to get around that problem. Also, since I am a noob, if I am doing anything else here that makes you cringe, I would love to find out how to write this properly.

```
(def posts (ref nil))
(defn reset-posts [] (dosync alter posts nil))

(defn fetch-posts [& options]
  (let [options (apply array-map options)]
    (or @posts
        (dosync alter posts (fetch :posts options)))))
```

Comment: Try asking on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not convinced that your transaction blocks (`(dosync alter`...) do what you think!

```
user=> (def posts (ref nil))
#'user/posts
user=> (dosync (ref-set posts [1 2 3 4 5]))
[1 2 3 4 5]
user=> @posts
[1 2 3 4 5]
user=> (dosync alter posts nil)
nil
user=> @posts
[1 2 3 4 5]
```

In `reset-posts`, you probably want `(dosync (ref-set posts nil))`, and in `fetch-posts`, the syntax fix would be `(dosync (ref-set posts (fetch :posts options)))`.

However, there's a race condition in `fetch-posts`, a check-then-act. Might not be that big of a deal; not sure who uses `fetch-posts`, but moving the `or @posts` bit inside the transaction would avoid a situation where 2 concurrent transactions both end up committing the alter.

With regard to retries of `fetch-posts`, yeah, that could happen, though your cache solution avoids most of them. I'm not sure there's a way around it without locking, though. Usually with I/O stuff in transactions you'd farm it out to an agent, but the transaction's success depends on the return value from `fetch`, so it's not clear to me how that'd work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice :) did some reading, and it seems like the difference between ref-set and alter is that alter runs a function to set the value, and ref-set just sets it to what you pass it, so yeah, nil as the param doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Sure thing. The other important distinction is that `dosync` takes forms to evaluate, so in the original example, `alter` never actually got called - just eval'ed to its value as a function, as did `posts` and `nil`. Something like `(dosync (alter posts assoc :foo "bar"))` would work if `@posts` started out as a map.

Answer (score 1):

So you're introducing the ref because you want to be able to not blow up memory when time passes, 'cause just using memoize around fetch-posts may lead to this, sooner or later, right ?

Maybe you could try an alternate approach : let fetch-posts be "pure", memoize-free. With this scenario, someone can call fetch-posts blindlessly, without having to fear OutOfMemoryExceptions. 
Indeed, maybe for some usecases, it may be sufficient to "cache the value" in a local of the calling code.

But the story does not end here, or I would not have taken the time to answer :-) : you can pretty easily have your "localized in time" memoize by rebinding fetch-posts using clojure.core/binding : from then, all the code in the same thread in the call stack will benefit from the bound memoized fetch-posts.
If you're using clojure 1.3 alpha, you'll need to declare the fetch-posts var as rebindable explicitly via the :dynamic metadata.

```
;; most simple definition
(defn ^:dynamic fetch-posts [& options]
  (let [options (apply array-map options)]
    (fetch :posts options)))

;; a la carte caching by the calling code (lexically scoped)
(let [posts (apply fetch-posts options)] ...)

;; a la carte caching by the calling code (dynamically scoped)
(binding [fetch-posts (memoize fetch-posts)] ...)
```

My last guess would be that you'd want to "memoize" in posts, in your original version, by indexing the posts by a key which would be the options seq, right ? Some maybe your code was not right ? (or you made the assumption that fetch-posts would always be called with the same args over and over ?)

Another idea. Use an agent to serialize write-access to posts and then ensure the call to fetch is only done when it is nil :

```
    (def posts (agent nil))

    (defn reset-posts [] (send posts (constantly nil)))

    (defn fetch-posts [& options]
      (let [options (apply array-map options)]
        (send-off posts #(or % (fetch :posts options)))
        (await-for (Long/MAX_VALUE) posts)
        @posts))
```

Comment: Yeah, I posted this question when it was in "sort of working" state, realized I had to cache on more then just results fairly quickly. The first examples you gave is probably the approach I will take, but thanks for the agent example, the more I learn about the clojure concurrency model the more I love it.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach which might be useful to move extensive computations outside the `dosync` is to use `delay`.

```
(defn fetch-posts
  [& options]
  @(dosync (or @posts (ref-set posts (delay (apply fetch :posts options))))))
```

Also note that your original code is *not* thread-safe since you access the ref outside the `dosync` and modify it based on this value afterwards in the `dosync`. But the value might have changed already between the `deref` and the `dosync`. Eg. by another thread calling `fetch-posts` in parallel.

Also the agent approach is questionable, because you cannot reliably read an agent. The value you get is consistent, but the access is not synchronised. Consider Laurent's example: between `await-for` and the `deref` another thread might already call `reset-posts` and you get `nil` instead of the post data. In this example this is probably a) far fetched and b) maybe a case one has to consider anyway, but there might be other use cases where this introduces a subtle race condition in more critical code.

tl;dr: Be careful what you do! Clojure is not magically thread-safe. Reason thoroughly about your solution and be aware of the implications.

Comment: that's true, there's a race condition inside fetch-posts with agents :-(